# I am trying to use Windows Task scheduler to run a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

The problem is that when I use the following:-

```
-noexit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command  "& ' C:\Program File(x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP" /ini-nul/script=C:\Users\Glen\Desktop\WinSCP\Downloadscript.txt"
```

I get the following error message;

> **The string is missing the terminator:'.
>
> - CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorID : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString**

It runs OK in Powershell both ise and V1.0 but will not work using Task Scheduler

Using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You have a `"` instead of `'` in your command line. Change it to this:

```
-noexit -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command  "& 'C:\Program File(x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP' /ini-nul/script=C:\Users\Glen\Desktop\WinSCP\Downloadscript.txt"
```

The winscp parameters seem to be incorrect as well. I assume

```
/ini-nul/script=...
```

should be

```
/ini=nul /script=...
```

Comment: And the last question would be ... why powershell in the first place? It seems like you are just starting winscp. You can do this directly.

Comment: I am trying to download images from a Raspberry Pi camera module and move them onto the PC attached hard drive. I am not sure how i can do this directly from WinSCP. The script I use comes from WinSCP (script download.txt.) I tried your suggestions above and got the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: See [WinSCP guide to scheduling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule) to learn how to start WinSCP directly from the Task Scheduler (though it's rather obvious).